# How to uninstall Webforms for marketers

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

How to uninstall Webforms for marketers module so that I can remove all references to this module?

(for reference: WFFM -2.2.0 rev. 111104)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're still looking for a solution, first, [inspect the content of the WFFM package](http://www.markstiles.net/Blog/2011/03/14/inspecting-packages.aspx) then based on what files and items you see, delete the files and remove the respective items in Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no real interface or function for uninstalling Sitecore modules (yet anyway). That said it doesn't mean that it is impossible.
If you open the package file (.zip) and browse it you will find that the structure contains both physical files installed in the file system together with a directory of items serialized to files. By traversing the structure in the package you can find out which items and files to remove from your solution.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Open WFFM package (.zip) file and remove installed WFFM files as per package form Sitecore.